# Show only numeric keyboard without numberPassword

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm trying to only show the numeric keyboard when typing into an edittext.
I know i can use 'android:inputType="number|phone"' and 'android:digits="0123456789"' to *almost* accomplish this. But this method still shows buttons like ()+-/*# which i don't want to show.
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJj4.jpg

Then i found 'android:inputType="numberPassword"', which shows a perfect, numeric only, keyboard. Simply numbers from 0-9, a delete button and an enter button. This is perfect, except for the fact that it hides whatever is typed into the edittext (like you would expect for a Password field).
Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW4sd.png

Is there any way to force the type of keyboard to be shown as only numbers 0-9, delete button and enter button, but without hiding the numbers that are typed in?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a utility method for toggle visibility.

```
//do:
hidePassword(editText, someText.getTypeFace(), false)

public static void hidePassword(EditText editText, Typeface typeface, boolean hidePassword){
    if (hidePassword) {
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        editText.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
    else {
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        editText.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
}
```